# Surprisingly similar hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I would like to ask you for pairs or even triples of statistical tests which are, surprisingly, similar.

By *similar* I mean they test essentially the same hypotheses and lead to approximately the same p value and by *surprisingly* I mean they are hardly found in statistical texts.

One for the start:

**Jonckheere-Terpstra-Test and test for Kendall's rank correlation**

The nonparametric 1-way ANOVA with ordered alternatives (known as "Jonckheere-Terpstra-Test") is similar to the standard test about Kendall's rank correlation, see e.g. [this link](http://www.inside-r.org/node/161722). The latter of the two methods has the big advantage of belonging to a meaningful measure of association that can also be equipped by a confidence interval.

Comment: I might just mention the obvious thing that there's no wonder or surprise, because comparing groups and correlating two variables (at least one of which is the grouping one) are two sides of the same coin and they are counterpart, being a significance test and a effect size, respectively. So there exist many examples of such "pairs". Most evident, perhaps, is ANOVA and Eta.

Comment: You are right, there are many cases like that. Sadly, these relations are not enough treated in introductory texts. But there are much different cases to mention: E.g. Wilcoxon's signed rank test for paired samples is the two-sample special case of the Quade test.

Comment: Yeah, There exist many statistical tests/coefficients identicies. Every advanced statistician has tended to invent or "invent" his own. Quede test? - it's new to me. Might you want to show its equivalence to Wilcoxon in your question (or self-answer?). In general, I respect your question a lot. A list of equivalencies might be a good idea.

Comment: `these relations are not enough treated in introductory texts` It is understandable. Knowing such relations calls for a glider view of a sufficiently experienced data analyst with a bit of philosophical disposition. "Introductory" text authors are seldom preoccupied with summarizing goals.